# why is tail recursion required in all implementations in scheme?

Tags: scheme, tail-recursion

Tail recursion is more efficient because it reuses the same stack frame instead of creating a new one, but why is this required for everything in scheme?

Comment: because of what you've just said. wait. it is not "required for everything in Scheme" to be tail-recursive; it is required of Scheme to correctly implement tail recursion, because TR is widely used in Scheme. And, because **`call/cc` would be impossible without it**.

Comment: Can't have call/cc without tail-calling? I don't see why you make this claim.

Comment: @JohnClements I meant to say "would be impossible to use it w/out proper TR". A call to `call/cc` should rewind the call stack; but without TR a call to a function preserves its call stack. So even if you allow it, there'd be a stack explosion. This was my thinking.

Comment: @WillNess: oh... I think you mean "a call to a continuation captured using call/cc should rewind the call stack"... and I agree, but tail-calling/tail-recursion is orthogonal to this; you can have a non-tail-calling language that still allows the stack-mangling caused by the use of a continuation.  In fact, Rhino, an open-source JavaScript implementation, is non-tail-calling but has a continuation-capture and -invocation mechanism.

Comment: @JohnClements interesting, I didn't know that (and yes this *is* what I meant... :) ) So the call to a captured continuation is different in Rhino then a regular call, then? I'll read me some more on that, thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tail recursion is mandated by the language's specification. Quoting from section [5.11](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-8.html#node_idx_250) of R6RS:

> Implementations of Scheme must be properly tail-recursive. Procedure calls that occur in certain syntactic contexts called tail contextsare tail calls. A Scheme implementation is properly tail-recursive if it supports an unbounded number of active tail calls. A call is active if the called procedure may still return. Note that this includes regular returns as well as returns through continuations captured earlier by call-with-current-continuation that are later invoked. In the absence of captured continuations, calls could return at most once and the active calls would be those that had not yet returned. A formal definition of proper tail recursion can be found in Clinger's paper [5]. The rules for identifying tail calls in constructs from the (rnrs base (6)) library are described in section 11.20.

The practical reason for this, is that tail recursion allows the implementation of efficient looping using recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Scheme does not have `goto`, so all looping is, ultimately, done using tail recursion. Without a proper tail recursion guarantee, there is no reliable way to provide looping in Scheme.

---

**Update:** I want to explain what I mean by "ultimately uses tail recursion". Let's look at the `do` macro, since @newacct mentioned it. For example:

```
(do ((i 1 (+ i 1)))
    ((> i 10))
  (display i)
  (newline))
```

As I mentioned, Scheme does not have `goto`, so it must get its looping from somewhere. It actually macro-expands to (something like) this:

```
(let loop ((i 1))
  (unless (> i 10)
    (display i)
    (newline)
    (loop (+ i 1))))
```

Notice that `loop` here is not a keyword or builtin function. It's a named function that's created by the named `let`<sup>†</sup>, and which is being invoked (via tail recursion) at the bottom of the `unless` form.

Really, all standard looping forms in Scheme use tail recursion. There's no getting away from it.

---

† Here's what the named `let` (loosely speaking<sup>‡</sup>) macro-expands to:

```
(letrec ((loop (lambda (i)
                 (unless (> i 10)
                   (display i)
                   (newline)
                   (loop (+ i 1))))))
  (loop 1))
```

‡ Strictly speaking, it macro-expands to:

```
((letrec ((loop (lambda (i)
                  (unless (> i 10)
                    (display i)
                    (newline)
                    (loop (+ i 1))))))
   loop)
 1)
```

Comment: there is `do` in scheme, but it is seldom used

Comment: @newacct `do` does not use `goto`. It macro-expands to a tail recursion on a named `let`.

Comment: [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-2.html#%_toc_%_sec_4.2.4) says that "Do is an iteration construct". It could be implemented as first-class just as well, not necessarily as a macro. It is as much a part of the language as named let, it seems. And Scheme has `call/cc`, it is `goto` on steroids. In fact *this* might be the real reason - without TR guarantee `call/cc` is unusable.

Comment: @newacct named `let` considered a more *Scheemly* way of doing things. :)

Comment: @WillNess Technically you _could_ implement `do` as built-in syntax rather than as a macro, but I can't imagine any implementation wanting to do that, since: 1. named `let` is strictly more general than `do` (all instances of `do` can be rewritten as named `let`, but not vice versa), and 2. `do` is very little-used. So thus, in practice, you really do need proper tail recursion to loop, unless you want to abuse `call/cc` for that purpose.

Comment: I agree, `do` feels a bit *unScheemly*. I think though, that wthout TR `call/cc` would really be impossible. Looping via `call/cc` would be ugly (or nice...?), but still possible.

Comment: (but without TR Scheme itself would be *unScheemly*). :)

Answer (score 0):

Without TR guarantee `call/cc` would be unusable. Looping in itself could be achieved via **`do`** [which is a part of the language](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/).

**edit**: this turned out to be not correct. See comments by John Clements at the question. A language can have non-TR function call mechanism but have a special separate mechanism for calling the continuations.

Comment: Speaking of which, here, tail-recurse on this: http://instagram.com/p/NObwZSkEAk/ ;-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Nicce! :) Ay, it is *yours*!